# How to get image data using file_get_content

Tags: php, mysql, web-services

```
    <?php
include("apiconfig.php");
global $api_key;
foreach($_REQUEST as $k=>$val)
        {
            $_REQUEST[$k]=input_clean_string( $val);
        }
if(isset($_REQUEST['api_key']) && !empty($_REQUEST['api_key']) && $_REQUEST['api_key']==$api_key && isset($_REQUEST['user_id']) && !empty($_REQUEST['user_id'])  ){
$user_id=$_REQUEST['user_id'];
$profile_image=file_get_contents('php://input');


if ($profile_image) {

    $sql="UPDATE users SET profile_image='".$profile_image."' WHERE user_id=".$user_id;
    mysql_query($sql);
}
echo $user= get_userdata($user_id); 
}else{

echo json_encode(array('errormsg' => 'Invalid access.'));

}
```

Here I'm not getting profile_image. I'm storing image data in to table in binery format (using blob, I'm storing data). Here `$profile_image` is empty

Answer (score 0):

try use stream_get_content function instead file_get_content. If you get resource type.

$profile_image=stream_get_content ('php://input');